# Plotly: How to plot a heat map from three lists: X, Y, Intensity

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I have 3 lists say:
 `x=[1,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9] y=[11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] intensity=[21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]`

the value of intensity is 21 at x=1 and y=11 and intensity is 22 at x=1 and y=12.

How to plot this using heat map in plotly express.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why 1 appears twice and 3 does not in the X coordinate list?

Comment: And do the X and Y values impart positional values? (i.e. since there is no Y=1, would the (1,1) coordinate have an intensity of 0?)

Comment: if the x and y lists are positional and you have the xaxis range from [1,9] and the yaxis range from [11,19], the majority of the heatmap cells won't have corresponding intensities